# Preg Match multiple br tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a textarea that users enter comments into and i am using nl2br to allow them to add spaces between blocks of text. I would like to replace occurrences where 3 or more br tags appear in a row and replace it with them all with a single tag.

one or two br tags don't get replaced they're fine but anymore more needs to be replaced with a single tag.

This is the regular expression i have so far

```
$comment = preg_replace('/(<br \/>){3,}/', '<br />', $comment);
```

$comment variable is

```
one<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
two<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
three<br />
<br />
four
```

Changing the regex to

```
$comment = preg_replace('/(<br \/>)/', '-', $comment);
```

replaces all the br tags with hyphens, so it seems like it's something to do with {3,} but i'm not sure.

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: post the content of comment variable.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem without some actual data. https://eval.in/208061

Comment: The regex looks fine but doesn't work for me either. @AvinashRaj you can check it here if you want http://regex101.com/r/aG3rJ8/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression. Since the repeating tags could be on the same line or separated by a newline sequence, you need to account for whitespace.

```
$comment = preg_replace('~(?:<br />\s*){3,}~', '<br />', $comment);
```

[Regex Explanation](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%28%3F%3A%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%5Cs*%29%7B3%2C%7D&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode) | [<kbd>**Code Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/208068)

If for some logical reason it removes certain whitespace you want retained, I would use ...

```
$comment = preg_replace('~(?:<br />\R?){3,}~', '<br />', $comment);
```

Comment: maybe add a *reason* for the change.

Comment: After doing some reading it appears it needs to be in a non-capturing group as apposed to a capturing group. adding ?: at the start of the brackets turns it into a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex also,

```
(?:<br \/>\n?){3,}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aG3rJ8/3)

By adding an optional  `\n` at the last  will match also a newline character if presents.